# Calculate 30 day average in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, moving-average

I realize there are other threads on this topic, but none of them seem to work for me and I'm not sure why. I'm hoping someone might be able to shed some light on my issue.

I have the following raw data, where there are multiple accounts for each date:

| Date | Account | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/26/2023 | AAA | 497 |
| 12/26/2023 | BBB | 328 |
| 12/26/2023 | CCC | 398 |
| 12/22/2023 | AAA | 997 |
| 12/22/2023 | BBB | 709 |
| 12/22/2023 | CCC | 943 |
| 12/21/2023 | AAA | 825 |
| 12/21/2023 | CCC | 130 |
| 12/20/2023 | AAA | 275 |

What I'm looking for is something like the result column below, where the result is the average of the last three values in the 'Sum of Value' column inclusive of that day (e.g., 625 = (647+920+309)/3). Given the source of the data, the goal would be to sum each day first, then calculate an average over the last three days:

| Date | Daily Sum | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20-Nov | $309 |  |
| 21-Nov | $920 |  |
| 22-Nov | $647 | $625 |
| 24-Nov | $1,204 | $924 |
| 27-Nov | $1,010 | $953 |
| 28-Nov | $1,184 | $1,132 |
| 29-Nov | $1,014 | $1,069 |
| 30-Nov | $629 | $942 |
| 1-Dec | $1,491 | $1,045 |
| 4-Dec | $1,417 | $1,179 |
| 5-Dec | $1,150 | $1,353 |
| 6-Dec | $1,412 | $1,327 |
| 7-Dec | $1,129 | $1,231 |
| 8-Dec | $1,270 | $1,271 |
| 11-Dec | $586 | $995 |
| 12-Dec | $1,105 | $987 |
| 13-Dec | $702 | $798 |
| 14-Dec | $1,430 | $1,079 |
| 15-Dec | $1,169 | $1,101 |
| 18-Dec | $1,693 | $1,431 |
| 19-Dec | $753 | $1,205 |
| 20-Dec | $803 | $1,083 |
| 21-Dec | $955 | $837 |
| 22-Dec | $2,649 | $1,469 |
| 26-Dec | $1,224 | $1,609 |

My problem is that no matter what formula I use, I'm only displaying the latest sum for a particular date ($1224 for 12/26, for example, instead of $1669). Can someone please help me understand how to do this properly given my data source?

Any help very much appreciated and happy holidays.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Measures similar to:

```
Daily Sum = SUM(Example1[Value])

Avg Daily 3 = 
  var thisDate = MAX(Example1[Date])
  var last3 = 
    TOPN(3,
      SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(ALL(Example1), Example1[Date] <= thisDate),
        Example1[Date],
        "Sum", [Daily Sum]
      ),
      [Date], DESC
    )
  return IF(COUNTROWS(last3) = 3, AVERAGEX(last3, [Sum]) )
```

Comment: This is great and worked for my use case. I understand the Daily Sum measure and thisdate variable, but would you mind describing what's happening in TOPN and the return statement please? Thanks very much.

Comment: `SUMMARIZE` is creating a calculated table grouped by `[Date]` with `Sum` as the daily sum. It is also filtered to only include the current row date (`thisDate`) and previous dates. Then `TOPN` is getting 3 rows from the calculated table ordered by the `[Date]` column in descending order. Ie get me the daily sum of the current date and the last two available dates. The `return` is checking that we have three rows, and if we do then do the average.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pity that you have included images of your data rather than the actual figures so that we can cut, paste and test solutions.
There also seem to be typos in your question. If I'm correct, the sum for 26/12 should be $1,22**3**. And the average of the 3 day's data 21,22 & 26 Dec should be 16**0**9
Having said that, surely you are almost there. Is there any reason why you can't do this on with a two step process? You have the daily totals so calculating the average  of 3 successive values is trivial - you already show it as "Result". If you don't want to display the intermediate daily values, just hide the "Sum of values" column.
The main problem seems to be irregular spacing of the dates and missing Accounts - there are only 2 sets for BBB whilst the rest are all AAA and CCC, except for 20 Nov which only has AAA. This makes it almost impossible to calculate your average in one step.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. I've edited to include tables instead of images. You're right on the sum, 1224 is rounded. Also, yes, the average of the Dec 21, Dec 22 and Dec 26 should be 1609. Given that i'm only concerned about averaging daily values, i didn't think the irregular spacing should be an issue. After all, if i have 1 account or 5 accounts for a specific day, doesn't matter, as long as I have a daily value. Also, I've presented this in excel format so as to convey the idea, but the idea is to create a measure of some kind for use in PowerBI. Really appreciate you taking a look.