# How to calculate moving average of a dataset with missing dates in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, moving-average

### Dataset I'm working with:

[TransactionDataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWFpW.png)

The index column is created by:

1. Referencing this Transaction Dataset in PowerQuery
2. Removing all other columns except the date column
3. Removing duplicates
4. and then indexing it in a separate table so that it looks like this in a separate table:
   [IndexDataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1A56.png)

Within the Transaction Dataset within the Model view, I've created a column named Index and used:
Index = RELATED('Index'[Index]) so now that the TransactionDataset includes an index.

### Objective

I'd like to get the average of the NET transaction for a rolling X days: [Raw Data from before + End Goal in a Power BI Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYhA0.png) - Should be average of the last 3 dates, not SUM in my screenshot.

### What I've tried so far:

###### I tried using the DATESBETWEEN function but because some of the dates are missing, it would pick up 0s for those missing dates as mentioned in some other questions posted here.

I tried different variations of using the existing dates field however the average seems to be WAY off.

###### I tried using the Index function since it wouldn't chronologically list the unique date.

This gave me repeating values for each and every row, for example: Moving Avg Last 3 = SUMX ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'TransactionDataset' ), 'TransactionDataset'[TxnType] = "BUY" || 'TransactionDataset'[TxnType] = "SEL" ), VAR CurrentIndex = 'TransactionDataset'[Index] // Assuming 'Index' is the name of your index column RETURN CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( 'TransactionDataset'[$ Amount)] ), FILTER ( ALL ( 'TransactionDataset' ), 'TransactionDataset'[Index] >= CurrentIndex - 2 && 'TransactionDataset'[Index] <= CurrentIndex ) ) )

Comment: Have you tried creating a calendar table? that's how you do it.

Comment: I tried creating a date table as well, one with weekends and one without weekends to experiment how the average would calculate.

Both were not giving the desired results but perhaps I made a mistake in that attempt due to frustration. What would be your recommended approach after having a date table?

The issue I ran across was that it would count the dates with no values as 0, and include that in the calculation of the average. - This is not desired, I would ideally like the last 3 days with values to be averaged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate 30 day average in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723576/calculate-30-day-average-in-power-bi)